# Wiki-style links. How to change color of links if the destination page doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have model WikiPage. WikiPage->text I get from database. I made method "wikify " and generate text on page by class::wikify($Page->getText()).
In text I have construction [link name], I generate link with this:

```
$text = preg_replace('@\[(.*) (.*)\]@', '<a href="\\1" class="<?php Wiki::httpresponse($\\1) ?>">\\2</a>', $text);
```

The idea is to check the url with function httpresponse and change class if there is no page.

httpresponce:

```
static public function httpresponse($url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
    curl_exec ($ch); 
    $intReturnCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
    if ($intReturnCode != 200 && $intReturnCode != 302 && $intReturnCode != 304) { return "red"; } else return "blue";
}
```

2 problems:

1. when I test httpresponce on my localhost pages it doesn't find them, when I test it on web pages, everything is ok.

   (checked links like `http://localhost:8080/category/page`, category is first module, page is isecond, homepage is module:category, action: index, category/page is route for module: page, action: show)
2. class of generated links remains `<?php Wiki::httpresponse($\\1) ?>` method httpresponce is not executing.

What can be done?
Maybe there is a better way to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

found solution.

```
$reg_inURL = "@\[(\w*)\/(\w*) (.*)\]\]@";
   preg_match_all($reg_inURL, $text, $matches);
   $count = 0;
   $links = count($matches[0]);
   foreach ($matches[0] as $pattern)
   {
    $cat = $matches[1][$count];
    $pag = $matches[2][$count];

    $q = WikiPageQuery::create()
        ->leftJoin('WikiPage.WikiCategory')
        ->where('WikiCategory.category_address = ?', $cat)
        ->filterByAddress($pag)
        ->findOne();
    if (!$q)
    {
        $link_class = 'red';
        $url = $cat.'/add';
    }
    else 
    {
        $link_class = 'blue';
        $url = $cat.'/'.$pag;
    }

    $title = $matches[3][$count];
    $text = str_replace  ($pattern, '<a href='.$url.' class='.$link_class.'>'.$title.'</a>', $text);
    $count = $count+1;
   }
```